# Font shows a box with an X through it, instead of correct symbol

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, text

I copy/pasted "ˈakSH(ə)n" into a text layer, when I'm scrolling through fonts, the text shows up properly.
[image: while going through fonts]

But when I hit enter to select a font, the symbols turn to boxes with an X through them.
[image: After selecting a font]

Seems to happen with all fonts.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The box with the X in it appears when there isn't a glyph mapped to that unicode character (U+0259) in the particular font.

I suggest you examine the entire glyph set for the fonts you're trying to use to see if the schwa exists in the font you want to use. If it does, replace that character with the one in the font itself.